# GDB will not step into a user defined function

Tags: c++, makefile, gdb

I am compiling some code for leftist heaps, and I want to step through my levelorder traversal function. However, whenever I reach a breakpoint at "theheap.levelorder()" and type "step", gdb passes over the code.

I am compiling with the -g flag and have tried -fno-inline to no avail. Why is this happening?

My makefile is as follows:

```
all:LeftistHeap.o lab10.o
        g++ LeftistHeap.o lab10.o -g -o lab10

lab10.o:LeftistHeap.h
        g++ -fno-inline -g -c lab10.cpp

LeftistMax.o:LeftistHeap.h LeftistHeap.cpp
        g++ -fno-inline -g -c LeftistHeap.cpp

clean:
        rm *.o *~ lab10
```

**EDIT:**
I have two levelorder() functions: one private, one public. i know this is probably unnecessary, but it shouldn't result in gdb acting like this.

levelorder is declared as follows in the .h file:

```
public:
        void levelorder();

private:
        void levelorder(LNode* node);
```

levelorder is defined as follows in the .cpp file:

```
void LeftistHeap::levelorder()
{
  levelorder(root);
}

void LeftistHeap::levelorder(LNode* node)
{ 
  queue<LNode*> currentLevel, nextLevel;
  currentLevel.push(root);
  while(!currentLevel.empty())
  {
    LNode* temp = currentLevel.front();
    currentLevel.pop();
    if(temp)
    {
      cout << temp->key << " ";
      if(temp->lchild != NULL)
        nextLevel.push(temp->lchild);
      if(temp->lchild != NULL)
        nextLevel.push(temp->rchild);
    }
    if(currentLevel.empty())
    {
      cout << endl;
      swapq(currentLevel, nextLevel);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could post the actual code? Have you looked at the compiler's assembler code that is generated?

Comment: not totally sure about this, but if `levelorder` is defined inline in the class definition, it might not be possible to not inline it in the compiled code, so if this is the case, I would try to move that function definition in the corresponding `.cc` or `.cpp`.

Comment: Try also to compile with `-O0`

Comment: I have posted the code. I'm not sure how to define a function inline, so I don't think that is the problem. The levelorder function is called in another client program just as "theheap.levelorder();"

Comment: @PiotrJaszkowski: adding this does not fix the problem. Thank you for your suggestion, though.

Comment: Any chance you could post complete code? Better still, minimal complete code? It would save us a lot of effort.

Comment: @Beta all of the code can be found here: https://github.com/conrosebraugh/eecs560lab10/tree/master/LeftistHeap

I can post it in an edit above, but I figured people wouldn't want to look at a page that long